# How do I find out if my Windows machine is running 32 or 64 bit OS?

Tags: windows

What command should I run to identify if I am running a 32 or a 64 bit Windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **start menu button**, then right click on **Computer** and select **Properties**, this will bring up basic info about your computer. Under system it will tell you your system type.

Comment: Will also tell you what Windows version you're running, what processor type, and how much RAM you have.

Comment: @DanielRHicks That is correct.